# Facebook Data Terms and agreement

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have found this statement at the Facebook terms.
(You will not include data you receive from us concerning a user in any advertising creative, even if a user consents to such use.)

I am not sure what is an advertising creative is, need more explanation about that.

BR

Answer (score 0):

By "advertising creative", they mean the text or graphics used in an advertisement.